# Finding upper triangular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I have this question, and im not sure I know how to solve it.

"Find an upper triangular $U$ (not diagonal) with $U^2 = I$ which gives $U=U^{-1}$".

Anybody who can help me getting the first steps of this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to look to a matrix $U=\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ 0 & c \end{pmatrix}$, compute $U^2$ and see what relationships $a$, $b$ and $c$ have to have in order to make $U^2 = I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix.

Comment: This would lead to a and c beeing -1, and b beeing 1. But doesnt that make the matrix diagonal? Im just figuring what the text means with the parenthesis "(not diagonal)"?

Comment: A diagonal matrix would be $b=0$.
And if $a=c=-1$, it won't work (you need $a+c=0$), but you are close

Comment: Ah okay, I thought a diagonal matrix would be if only the left corner would be zero - thanks for the correction... I see, either a or c should be 1 - thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

I see that no one explicitly gave an answer. I cannot give it in a comment (not enough reputation), so here it is. The answer for a $2 \times 2$ matrix is $a = 1$, $b \in \mathbb{R^\ast}$ and $c = -1$. It comes from the equations $a = c^2 = 1$ and $b(a+c) = 0$ (which you get after multiplying $U$ with itself and identifying the result with the identity matrix $I$). Then, making sure that $U$ is not a diagonal matrix requires that $b \neq 0$. Thus, the second equation becomes $a + c = 0$.This gives the final answer $U =
\left( 
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & b\\
0 & -1\\
\end{array} 
\right)$.